# No sound when streaming mp4 file in red5 server

Tags: red5, jwplayer

I installed red5 server is used for playback video.

As oflademo page, I tried to playback video via .mp4 file. I uploaded file demo.mp4 to  /usr/local/red5/webapps/oflaDemo/streams/

In client, i used JWPlayer to play the videos via RTMP. Here is script to play the video demo.mp4

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
    'bufferlength': '10',
    'smoothing' : 'false',
    'quality':'best',
    'autostart':'true',
    'icons': 'true',
    'allowscriptaccess': 'always',
    'allownetworking': 'all',
    'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
    'file': 'demo.mp4',
    'streamer':'rtmp://192.168.1.139/oflaDemo/',
    'image':'/jwplayer/logo.png',
    'controlbar': 'bottom',
    'width': '720',
    'height': '306'
    });
</script>
```

But,  JWPlayer only streaming video and NO sound. 
I tried in demo page of red5 is oflademo , but the same result.

How to fix to streaming mp4 in red5 to have sound and video ?

Answer (score 0):

The audio in the mp4 file must have an audio codec that red5 recognizes; which at this time consists only of AAC.